# determine the resulting class of an expression

Tags: java, reflection

Is there an easy way to decide the resulting Java Class of a Java mathematical expression? For example, I can calculate the resulting class of something like String + double but is there something out there give the resulting class of any valid expression of mixed classes at runtime?

Background: I need this as I am using Java reflection to call methods with arguments at runtime. The arguments have been parsed from text into Expression objects where Expression is my class for handling expressions. An Expression can be made up of other Expressions. So for instance I may be parsing code like:

```
double c = 2.2;
double d = 3.3;
long e = 4;
int f = 1000;
double a = 0;
double b = 0;
MyObject object = new MyObject();
object.getSomething(a, b, (c+d+e)/f);
```

I know the Classes of a and b because they are defined variables but the Class of third argument needs to be calculated before I can do something like:

```
Method method = MyObject.class.getMethod("getSomething", double.class, double.class, ????);
```

Comment: Why would you not just use the type expected by the Method? In any case the result will need to get typecasted to that type.

Comment: What are the types of c, d, e, and f? The rules for promotion of numeric types can be found in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @sujitv There may be many methods with same name but different arguments.

Comment: @David Conrad types of c, d, e and f are always known, it is the resulting class that I want to determine in each situation. I will edit the code to remove doubt about c, d, e and f

Comment: See JLS section [5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

Comment: Why are you trying to work out the getMethod parameters from a sample call, rather than from the method's declaration?

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan I am executing user supplied code (yuk), there may be many methods with the same name. I need to determine which method to call. getMethod() is the first try, if there is no exact match I cycle through all methods with that name and look for the best. In any case I need to know the type/class of the third argument.

Comment: Can you constrain the forms of expression you have to deal with? The nature of the class hierarchy?

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan I am using ANTLR4 to parse the expressions successfully and don't particulary want to constrain the expression form. I only accept Java types/classes + my own classes + class and sub classes in the user supplied file that I am parsing - all subject to blacklists (eg no System)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first place, you can't know the *classes* of `a` and `b` because `a` and `b` are not *objects*.  They are local variables of the *primitive type* `double`.  In java you have two basic kind of types:  primitive types (`boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, and maybe `void`) and class types.  However, there is also a mechanism called *autoboxing* (and *autounboxing*) that automatically converts when necessary between primitive types and their corresponding "primitive wrapper classes" (`Boolean`, `Byte`, `Character`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, and `Double`).  You can use this automatic conversion to determine the type of an expression.  Example:

```
byte a= 10 ;
float b= 16.3 ;
int c= 34 ;
Object o= a * b + c ;
o.getClass();    //  Should be Double or one of the primitive wrapper classes in the general case
//  You can easily convert this to double.class through an if/elseif sequence
//  or a Map.
```

A note of attention:  When one mixes variables (and/or also parameters and/or return values) of primitive types and wrappers classes, it's very easy to lose track of types.  In particular, the Java reflection API works mostly if not exclusively with wrapper classes.  This means, for example, that method `invoke` supports parameters of class types only and thanks to autoboxing Java will convert any primitive type into a wrapper object, even if the target method really expects the primitive (in which case there will be an internal conversion back to the primitive type immediately before the reflective call).  As a good experiment, try turning autoboxing/unboxing off if your compiler or IDE supports it.  If not this, configure them to produce warnings on autoboxing/unboxing.

Now, if your numeric values are represented in a polymorphic way (as String, Object, or similar), then you will need to define your own rules for the resulting type of the operations (or model them after the Java language itself) and implement them accordingly.  This is because Java autoboxing/unboxing is a *static* mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Mario Rossi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821077/1798593).

In addition, even if you were using reference expressions, you cannot in general deduce the types of the formal arguments from the types of the actual arguments on a sample call. Consider this program:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    double a = 3.0;
    new Test().myMethod(a);
    Method method = Test.class.getMethod("myMethod", Double.class);
    System.out.println(method);
  }

//  public void myMethod(Double d) {
//    System.out.println("Double version");
//  }

  public void myMethod(Number d){
    System.out.println("Number version");
  }
}
```

As presented, it fails with a NoSuchMethodException, because I'm looking for a Double argument and the only method expects a Number. If I uncomment the first `myMethod` declaration, the `getMethod` call succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the assumption that the objective is close to full Java code interpretation.

The information about expression types is provided, directly or by reference, in the Java Language Specification, [Chapter 15. Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). The actual number of rules that need to be implemented is smaller than it might appear, because many groups of expression forms share the same conversion rules. For example, as already mentioned in a comment on the question, binary operators with numeric operands, including operands that can be unboxed to numeric, generally use [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

I have looked, unsuccessfully, for short cuts for finding the right `Method` object for a given call. You may need to actually go through the steps described in [15.12. Method Invocation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). If so, you can use the `getMethods` methods instead of `getMethod` and apply the rules to the array of `Method` references.

Comment: Yes, you have uncovered my secret, I have built a Java interpreter in Java which is a type of madness that is so often derided but seems necessary if you want web based coding available to users of your framework eg look at SalesForce.com